# C# Regex optional match

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have some page content which contains multiple occurrences of the below line of code:

```
<li class="r"><h3><a href="/test-url.htm">test string</a></h3></li>
```

I'm using .NET Regex to find all the occurrences in the content and return me the href of the anchor tag.

My problem is that sometimes the `<li>` has quotes wrapped around the class (as shown above) but others don't and just have: `class=r`

I need the match against both with and without quotes.

I've tried various methods but nothing seems to have worked yet. They all match when there is a quote, but not without a quote. Below is my current attempt:

```
Regex _Regex = new Regex(@"<li class=(?:"")g([^>])*>((?!<h3).)*<h3([^>])*><a\shref=""(?<URL>[^""]*)""([^>])*>((?!</li).)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Regex isn't very good at dealing with HTML. If you're just trying to find duplicates you may be better off using xpath

Comment: I know I'm not answering your question, but you shouldn't be using regular expressions to parse HTML. You will be much better off using the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.

Comment: +1 this idea, very easy to use.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Does the Html Agility Pack require valid HTML? A few places I have opening `<li>` with no closing `</li>` and I don't have control over the content to make it valid.

Comment: @Scrooby Its fairly tolerant - give it a try and see.

Comment: @Kragen: Although useful, this should be a comment rather than an answer

Comment: -1 Not an answer and I hate this "burn the witch" attitude on SO when it comes to parsing HTML with regex.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ this seems like a useful answer to me; lots of answers on SO reccomend alternative approaches to a problem. This answer is more than just "dont.. regex.. html `[link to ___the answer___]`."

Comment: @agf "the answer" as you call it is a joke post that should've ran its course years ago. It boggles my mind why people are still linking to it

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ I agree.. that was my point, this answer doesn't fall into the "burn the witch and link to the answer" trap.

Comment: I fail to see what's bad about using RegEx if you have a static page. Sure, RegEx is not even to close to be good to *parse* HTML, but if all you need is one string from somewhere in the document, why not? If the page changes, you'll have to adapt anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the format you want is

""?

Not

?:

The question mark marks the preceding char as optional.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to match and capture an optional first quote, so the group ends up containing either a quote or an empty string.  Then you use a backreference at the end of the word to match the same thing again.

```
@"<li class=(""?)r\1[^>]*>"
```

On a side note, this appears three times in your regex, and it's wrong: `([^>])*`.  It *matches* what you want it to, but it only *captures* the last character.  If you need to capture those segments, you should move the asterisk inside the group.  If you *don't* need to capture it, just get rid of the parentheses like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Here is part of the regex. I think you know how to finigh it:

```
<li class=["r]+?>
```

or

```
<li class=["]?r["]?>
```

both of them works.